# Sobolev inequality for cubes

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Consider the fallowing result from Evans, 2010, page 279:

Let $U$ be a bounded, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and suppose $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Assume $1 \leq p < n$, and $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$. Then $u \in L^{p^\ast}(U)$, with the estimate
$$
||u||_{L^{p^\ast}(U)} \leq C ||u||_{W^{1,p}(U)},
$$
the constant $C$ depending only on $p,n$ and $U$.

It's clear we can't apply the obove result for a cube, since its boundery is not $C^1$. On the other hand, once we can apply the result for a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and we can put a cube inside a ball and vice versa, is it true that the result is also valid for a general cube? That is, I want to know if there's a constant $C > 0$ such that
$$
||u||_{L^{p^\ast}(Q)} \leq C ||u||_{W^{1,p}(Q)}, \forall u \in W^{1,p}(Q),
$$
where $Q = B_{r}(0)$ is a cube in the maximum norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The proof only required $\partial \Omega$ to be $C^1$ in order to guarantee $u$ has a Sobolev extension. Though $C^1$ is sufficient for this to be true it is not necessary. It is also true if $\partial \Omega$ is Lipschitz as in the case of a cube (for references see the second paragraph on p.2206 of [this paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272601/1-s2.0-S0022123610X00039/1-s2.0-S0022123610000133/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjENf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCXGz5nRsM%2F8yi%2BAKEL7CuSMLZieXgrt1pl8ugaLKdEBQIhAPpp8f0L5YwdMO0rbNp2DqTXI9O7WYb5CGkbNFxlgDGRKtsECLD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQBBoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgzMZEgp0XjIlLGXWd8qrwSDROxSHaNBlkyieQZ1DAvknhIWGDgCJ9oZcixO4d9kG4rMiA%2Bu3uJSIfHCreYEbbF8eifpsbTemmabhd4fwtI7VhCX0RD9JKFkNJ48Juzo9alCHt39hS7N5rapfZLPLKqRBmrTD5fKawm%2BCRtQLNPSQWNKOrvAxNkfemGzXh%2BJahp9Mq%2BzcIs1aW118aiPhY7jhjvZlfCpoCu18mXxPwDGUwuF3iTK8dhYO2BUKPgzm2o7p%2BNK7LhaIzyStjvdcTegI698YlvF8kTjeVxJ1%2FHcxLwxUWpsthvN8ywbQ2NgLvgWDjv3UmZL7jEIWUZba1dwG1jvaQUx7NIM9dLLyeFE%2FVMi8LazGDn0by2Oo%2B9Rki8EZx1XpF%2F8FQMCe2v%2FmVkKnWt4qvJ3IuIjQXK3so6DkbP%2Fn40ZpdIInXJ4%2BsevoOeopsIWAdelGu0HqpyKiDNq4CA8ZQD%2FEbqYDoHxy3b8cPM%2Bln2cdoVpF2lXR7JO3x2jNOfiUXlMvoww7fVVDmEjAMZZp2YsnXsMcuWjNWXkQZqStB1pF%2Bsk6CeljGKjH%2FLO5fexjrrkBtzvQErDMoIlYlodsE2KUHECgtIDD3aQT4WjgQNujQ%2F%2BvPNqFH9lk%2FyXU7Hifg6JOuJ8%2FhFUX%2B7pcAdSslblPf9O8lbE6TbfPROOoB3WFEYzo%2FVcw%2FMXt%2FMtgAlPLQFR1hN8KTYFly%2B79K6PMRQwpWgU6XKqR2iEqYhvJrMluDVFNkz2fnyzMJypi5QGOqgBQT%2F73dVIv%2B1%2Bb0jLoItzPLVfi7F6dGtNqSudzXyOuZWUN4sF44amYPv1V5Jx8DqNE9DOitYLk6hbP20eUIh14vXAHzaxw8xEvZ4LSXyrHuSc7lumgDRZeSqrI2FdcLaheW%2BF1O0DVSzrgOokFgLQKscURYErLmc4MqNLmHOHgcVu5IONKvCDiJDT%2BYjOoMFj2SEPUWMVswViWguwm%2BRkaJnD0TS%2FLrQ6&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220516T232341Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYYAQ7SICL%2F20220516%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=9df52cce9ce53e541920ed0a379e74a01898c85ae16af4060b052d6f00fc71c1&hash=fc33471e9c0d964d05c89eef46a438e2a47f12a1d894ac57dfaf00c4d59e3cb5&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022123610000133&tid=spdf-d6e3d308-7719-4380-ae1c-379cb734ab75&sid=7e3dd6fa7d648145fc9a9fd3020c245b42efgxrqa&type=client&ua=59570256030400045b&rr=70c7dcce9eb6fe91). In fact, this proof still works on any Sobolev extension domain.

Comment: Thank you very much @JackT

Comment: Just just to be registered, using @JackT tip, I found this notes https://sites.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/jyv-98b.pdf   , which has the result Jack said, see page 20, Proposition 34.